# Middle Sidebar Advertising

Tags: discussion, announcement, advertising

As you all know, advertising is an important source of revenue for Stack Overflow and it helps us support all the sites across the Stack Exchange Network and the resources that go into maintaining and improving the experience on the platform. We are going to be introducing middle sidebar ads, which have been on the main Stack Overflow site for years, to some of the tech sites including Code Review.

The middle sidebar ads have the same standards as any other ads on the platform. Ads are non-intrusive and static. Ads go through a vetting process to ensure they are appropriate for the communities on Stack Exchange. If you see an ad that may not follow our established standards and guidelines, you can let us know by using the "**report this ad**" functionality. Here is a mockup of what these will look like when two ads are shown (the existing ad placement and the new middle sidebar ad placement):

[image: sample of ads on the middle side bar of the site]

This ad space won’t be available for display until May 10<sup>th</sup> because we wanted to give you a heads-up before you started seeing them. Ads are an essential line of business for us and we’re committed to giving you advanced notice whenever we introduce a new form of advertising on the network sites. If you have any questions or concerns, please let us know.

Comment: "Ads go through a vetting process to ensure they are appropriate for the communities on Stack Exchange." Last I heard on MSE a while ago there were lots of reports of inappropriate ads, and ones which some deemed to violate user privacy. Has the situation now changed?

Comment: Yea, SE has a long history of not vetting the ads properly. So we'll see before we believe it, probably.

Comment: @Peilonrayz I answered a question about privacy concerns here https://retrocomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1198/middle-sidebar-advertising/1199#1199